# Burn [javascript-functions] or synonymize with [javascript]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Apparently, we have a [javascript-functions](/questions/tagged/javascript-functions) tag, with 221 questions and no tag wiki. This tag seems quite pointless; there are no other [somelanguage-functions](/questions/tagged/somelanguage-functions) tags and there aren't really any special things about JavaScript functions as opposed to any other language.

Instead of using this tag, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)+[function](/questions/tagged/function) would be ideal.

I propose either burning it or synonymizing it with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Burned! No synonym, because I can’t see anybody ever doing that again.